# IE not seeing Alt-D

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ae7Ed/7/ - that looks for an Alt key and a 'D' key pressed while focus is in the Results area:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log ("document keydown: keyCode = " + e.keyCode);
    if((e.keyCode == 68) && e.altKey){      // Alt-D
            console.log ("document keydown: Alt-D entered");
    }
 });
```

Firefox, Safari, and Chrome all see each character when entered by itself and they see the case where Alt is held down while D is pressed.  IE (I'm running IE10) sees each key when it is entered by it self but does not see the case where Alt is held down while D is pressed.

Does anyone understand what's going on with IE here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, Firefox and IE, Alt-D is processed by the browser to move the focus to the URL bar.

Apparently, Chrome lets the page see the keystroke first and IE does not - this is probably behavior that is not specified in the standards.  Alt keys in general are reserved for system shortcuts or top level app operations (the browser, not your web page is the app in this case).  If possible, you should use Ctrl keys for your app.

One guess is that what happens is that IE processes the keystroke and moves the focus to the address bar immediately and that prevents any further keyboard routing to your web page.  Other browsers process the keystroke slightly differently which allows the web page to see it.

FYI, a Google search reveals that javascript has not been able to capture Alt+D in IE since IE8 and I found no work-arounds.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll use Shift+D.